# Parsing JSON string using OPENJSON giving error despite a valid JSON is provided

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to parse a JSON string using SQL in SQL Server.
Below is the JSON string.

```
 DECLARE @json nvarchar(max)
 SET @json=
'{"value":[
           {
           "branch code": "2010",
           "rfq type": 1,
           "created": "20220930 12:31:39",
           "from": "MUNDRA",
           "to": "BANGALURU",
           "vehicle gate in time": "20220930 12:34:55",
           "GROSSWT": "",
           "do accepted date": "20220930 12:31:39",
           "indent type": 1,
           "indent number": "446/1",
           "invoice data": "",
           "is milk run": false,
           "do weight": ""}]}'
```

I am using below query to parse this but getting error:

```
    SELECT  j1.[key] AS ColumnName
    --,CAST(j1.value AS int) AS LastUpdatedValue
    FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.value') j1
    --CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.value) j2
```

The error I am getting as below:

```
   Msg 13609, Level 16, State 4, Line 21
   JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character ' ' is found at position 
   13.
```

As the msg suggest, there is an issue with JSON text. But I have checked in [jsonlint.com](https://www.jsonlint.com) and found that the above JSON is a valid one.

**Edit**

I am expecting the below table.

```
 ColumnName    LastUpdatedValue
  created         20220930
```

Hope this clears the doubts.

Not able to understand what I am missing here.

Comment: What version of sql server are you using and what are you expecting out? Unable to recreate your problem , I can even reference the properties within the the object in the array (what is lastupdatedvalue supposed to represent?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your trying to acccomplish, but I'm able to grab the latest object in the array with the following (your code with minor alterations on the select / order. Also added an extra object with the "created" key changed to "20220927 12:31:39" from "20220930 12:31:39".

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max)
 SET @json=
'{"value":[
           {
           "branch code": "2010",
           "rfq type": 1,
           "created": "20220927 12:31:39",
           "from": "MUNDRA",
           "to": "BANGALURU",
           "vehicle gate in time": "20220930 12:34:55",
           "GROSSWT": "",
           "do accepted date": "20220930 12:31:39",
           "indent type": 1,
           "indent number": "446/1",
           "invoice data": "",
           "is milk run": false,
           "do weight": ""},{
           "branch code": "2010",
           "rfq type": 1,
           "created": "20220930 12:31:39",
           "from": "MUNDRA",
           "to": "BANGALURU",
           "vehicle gate in time": "20220930 12:34:55",
           "GROSSWT": "",
           "do accepted date": "20220930 12:31:39",
           "indent type": 1,
           "indent number": "446/1",
           "invoice data": "",
           "is milk run": false,
           "do weight": ""}]}'

SELECT TOP 1 j1.[key] AS ObjectIndex
    , j1.[value] AS [Object]
    , JSON_VALUE(j1.[value], '$.created')
    --,CAST(j1.value AS int) AS LastUpdatedValue
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.value') j1
ORDER BY JSON_VALUE(j1.[value], '$.created') DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduce your trouble with the following code... Not sure that it works since the copy/past can arrange some chars...

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max)
 SET @json=
'{"value":[
         ​ {
           "branch code": "2010",
           "rfq type": 1,
           "created": "20220930 12:31:39",
           "from": "MUNDRA",
           "to": "BANGALURU",
           "vehicle gate in time": "20220930 12:34:55",
           "GROSSWT": "",
           "do accepted date": "20220930 12:31:39",
           "indent type": 1,
           "indent number": "446/1",
           "invoice data": "",
           "is milk run": false,
           "do weight": ""}]}';
SELECT  j1.[key] AS ColumnName
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.value') j1
```

It is why I give a copy of the trouble with a picture

[image]

In fact in my cas I have a char UNICODE u200B / #8203 non printable that induce a fine mess !

Replace manually all non printable chars by nothing or spaces.

Comment: can you please provide a code snippet?

Comment: I am not a specialist of text editor... You must use an appropriate external tool to do so...